# Multiple Relationships

Tags: relationships

This one's a little hairy. I have 3 channels: Products, Where to Buy Product and Retailers. We're displaying a Where to Buy dialog on the Products page. So I have 6 relationships on the Where to Buy Product channel: one to the Products channel, and 5 to the Retailers channel. (Yes, I have retailer_1, retailer_2, and so on.)

The Retailers channel is just an image for the retailer's logo. The Where to Buy Product channel is the product reference, and 5 sets of retailer references, and associated links to the retailer's website for that product.

Here's the code I put together:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="1"}

{reverse_related_entries channel="where_to_buy_product"}
    {retailer_1}<br>
    {link_1}<br>
    {related_entries id="retailer_1"}
    <img src="{retailer_logo:logo}" ><br>
    {/related_entries}

    {retailer_2}<br>
    {link_2}<br>
    {related_entries id="retailer_2"}
    <img src="{retailer_logo:logo}" ><br>
    {/related_entries}
{/reverse_related_entries}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So I got to the first level, where I can display the link to the retailer's website; but the second level, reaching to the Retailers channel, doesn't seem to work. I'm getting a funky code in curly braces that changes on each request. ({REL[79][retailer_1]AT42ME0eREL} ) I even tried switching to reverse_related_entries, even though that doesn't make sense to me, and apparently, it doesn't make much sense to EE either. (It dumped the {reverse_related_entries} tags.)

Can anyone help me make this work? I hope I have the concepts down right. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See the ground we've covered before: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7552/cross-referenced-relationships and http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7640/self-referenced-relationships.

Comment: Yes, Derek, you're absolutely right. I reviewed these questions and they are, indeed, very relevant to this issue. I resolved the last problem by switching to Playa, and this was the solution here as well. I was hoping to get the Relationship field type to work for me. I'm wondering if it's ever useful in any situation. Apologies for wasting bandwidth.

Comment: No apologies necessary! The built-in Relationship field is great for simple relationships where you don't need to next multiple relationships. A little birdie told me that EE's relationship field might be getting completely revamped very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I need to deal with complex relationships in EE I always turn to [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa). That should provide you with a nice way to make the associations and also to return the relationships from simple tags in the templates. It's a commercial addon but if complex relationships between your channel data are core to your site then it's worth the investment in time it will save you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Tied Entries plugin - it allows you to reach data that's more than one relationship away: http://engaging.net/products/tied-entries

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about Tied Entries, @JamesSmith. I already have Playa on this project, so that's the one I've used. But good to know there are alternatives.